On click of image carousel with lightbox, taking to image URL and then showing lightbox
I have a WordPress website where I am using Elementor Image Carousel in Blocksy theme. Here are the option I have selected for the images:

Link - Media File
Lightbox - Yes

When I click on the image, first I am navigated to media URL - /wp-content/uploads/image - and when I go back, I see the lightbox (default one with Elementor) opened with the image in full screen.
Here, on click of a image, I want to just open the lightbox without navigating to /wp-content/uploads/image path. How can I achieve this?
I tried running the below jQuery and also similar PHP code using WP Code Light Plugin.
In the below code, I tried to prevent the default behaviour of the anchor tag.
But even with this, the Media URL is opening.
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Ensure the script runs after the DOM is fully loaded
    $('.carousel a').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default link behavior

        // Get the href attribute of the clicked link
        var href = $(this).attr('href');

        // Ensure the lightbox plugin is available and has a method to open images
        if (typeof $.featherlight === 'function') {
            $.featherlight(href); // Open the lightbox (replace with the correct method if using another plugin)
        } else {
            console.error('Featherlight plugin is not loaded or available.');
        }
    });
});

How do I solve this? I am ok to use any free Carousel unless it supports Image view in full screen on click.

does the console.log anything? also check the console for errors (use Preserve log in DevTools)

Ok, will check. Here the issue is with default light box. If I use fancyBox plugin, this issue is not happening. But only one image will be opened in light box. There will be no navigation to next image.

What is contradictive? Please provide more info

I don't know the plugin but "Link - Media File" makes it link to the media file which you don't need because you have a lightbox. True, the lightbox should have handled this, but maybe removing the link would help

Please edit your question and clarify what's wrong with your code.  "didn't work" is not very descriptive of the problem. What exactly isn't working?  When you debug your code, at what point is it not doing what you expect?

If I make the link to None, the lightbox option wont come. Also I can't even click on the image.

"Ok, will check." - are you still not done with that, or why is there no feedback given here regarding this?

Go to site settings
Lightbox
Disable all except Image Lightbox.
